# Why does this code populate every array?

Tags: ruby

I have this piece of code that creates an array of arrays (`[[],[],[]]`) and an iterator that attempts to populate the respective arrays with numbers (shown below)

```
array = Array.new(3,[])
10.times do
  array[0] << 2
  array[1] << 3
  array[2] << 4
end
```

When I execute this code, I expected to see this

```
[[2,2,2,2,etc....],[3,3,3,3,etc...],[4,4,4,4,4...etc]]
```

but instead I get this:

```
[[2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4....repeat],[2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4....repeat],[2,3,4,2,3,4,2,3,4....repeat]]
```

I've tried to walk through it with `byebug` and it makes no sense to me. What is going on here?

Comment: `array.map(&:object_id)` can be illuminating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.new(3, [])` is not equivalent to `[[],[],[]]`. It is equivalent to `array = []; [array, array, array]`, an array of three references to the same array. After `array[0] << 2`, you have `[[2], [2], [2]]`, because all three elements point at the same array.

What you want is `Array.new(3) { [] }`, with a block specifying the default; this way, a new `[]` is created for each element.

Even better, your whole code can be written as:

```
Array.new(3) { |i| Array.new(10, i + 2) }
```

Comment: Or even `Array.new(3) { |i| [i + 2] * 10 }` which is shorter to type and some people may find more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The initializer you use is meant to be used with immutable objects, like creating an array of n times the same integer. For mutable objects use the block version. Here's the solution to your problem:

```
array = Array.new(3) { [] }

10.times do
  array[0] << 2
  array[1] << 3
  array[2] << 4
end

array[0]
#=> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation

> The second argument populates the array with references to the same
>   object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you need to
>   instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as Symbols,
>   numbers, true or false.
>
> To create an array with separate objects a block can be passed
>   instead. This method is safe to use with mutable objects such as
>   hashes, strings or other arrays:

```
Array.new(4) { Hash.new } #=> [{}, {}, {}, {}]
```

> This is also a quick way to build up multi-dimensional arrays:

```
empty_table = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
```

Therefore, your code first line should be

```
array = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
```